# Firebase auth automatically signs me back in after logout

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My login function works fine but after logging out it redirects me back to my login landing page. The AuthState in the login js doesnt change is it a bug or do i have an error in my code.

Login.js

```
function loginBtn(){
   var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
   var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPass).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
console.log(error.Message);
window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

});
}


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
if(user) {      
    window.location = '/home';
}

});

function recaptchaCallback() {
 $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
};
```

Auth.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {

} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  alert('NOT LOGGED IN');
  window.location='/';
}
});

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
    alert('SIGNED OUT');
  window.location='/';
}
```

Comment: Can you paste code of  `login.html` and `Auth.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by placing the OnAuthStateChanged to document ready since the listener is too slow to load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {      
        window.location = '/home';
    }

  });

});
```